# Touchbar support in python

Tags: python, macos, macbookpro-touch-bar

Is there a library yet that supports using the touchbar in python? Any bindings, or a way to for example call some `C` functions that alter things on the touchbar?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Take a look at [PyObjC](https://pyobjc.readthedocs.io/en/latest/core/intro.html). It provides methods for calling Objective-C functions from Python. It's a great way to play with macOS APIs from Python.

From the website:

> The PyObjC project aims to provide a bridge between the Python and Objective-C programming languages.

The website also states the important detail that

> The most important usage of this is writing Cocoa GUI applications on Mac OS X in pure Python. See our tutorial for an example of this.

which would indicate that you'd be able to build a touch bar interface using PyObjC.

Comment: For anyone interested, it looks as if the website has moved to https://pyobjc.readthedocs.io/en/latest/core/intro.html